# how to put sprites in grid in spritekit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm new to spritekit and for practicing purpose I want to make a crossword game in which i could place the sprites in grid (rows and columns) in a specific order in which only one word will be there at multiple places and rest of the members of the grid will be random letters
the grid will consist of 10x12 rows and columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make grid with 2 inside loops

```
for var i=0; i<10; i++ {
    for var a=0; a<12; a++ {
       let sprites = SKSpriteNode()// your sprite with image name. 
       sprites.position = CGPoint(x:50 * a+1 , y:50*i+1) // write your position here.
       self.addChild(sprites)
    }



let spriteArray = [SKSpriteNode]() // Empty array of sprites in class property.
for var x=0; x<numberOfLetters; x++ {
    // write your code here 
    spriteArray.append(letterSprite)
}
```

Comment: It will just add the single sprite on the whole matrix, i want to add multiple sprites for e.g a-z alphabet and each one of that letter is in png form, for that would I have to add them all in to array and then plot it or should I plot it directly through this above mentioned method ?

Comment: yes you can add them into the array with a separate function then if you want to access them in this loop. For example, if you want to add them randomly you should write  let x = arc4random_uniform(numberOfLetters) then self.addChild(spriteArray[x])

Comment: than how to put them in array ? i've searched over internet but i didnt find any suitable way for it

Comment: You can also look at the programming guide of swift. https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/the-swift-programming-language/

Comment: well i'm doing it in objective c

Comment: Sorry I can't help but you can find many tutorials about objective-c in youtube and google.

Comment: well no problem at all.. Thanks alot for your help